# Issue with double property in a generated class from a WSDL file

Tags: c#, wsdl, .net-6.0

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with a double property in a class generated from a WSDL file. Let me walk you through the code and the problem I'm facing.

First, I have a foreach loop where I'm performing some calculations and creating objects of a class called FeeType. These objects are then added to a list called FeeTypesList. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
foreach (var receipt in receiptValues)
{
    decimal rtd = Convert.ToDecimal(realisation.ReceiptAmount);
    decimal actualAmount = // some calculated value.

    FeeType builtObject = new FeeType()
    {
        CaseId = receipt.CaseId,
        ReceiptId = receipt.ReceiptId,
        ReceiptEffectiveDate = receipt.ReceiptEffectiveDate,
        FeeAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Round(actualAmount, 1)),
    };

    FeeTypesList.Add(builtObject);
}
```

The FeeType class is generated from a WSDL file and includes a FeeAmount property of type double. Here's what it looks like:

```
public partial class FeeType
{
    private int caseIdField;
    private int receiptIdField;
    private System.DateTime receiptEffectiveDateField;
    private double feeAmountField;

    public int CaseId
    {
        get { return this.caseIdField; }
        set { this.caseIdField = value; }
    }
    
    public int ReceiptId
    {
        get { return this.receiptIdField; }
        set { this.receiptIdField = value; }
    }
 
    public System.DateTime ReceiptEffectiveDate
    {
        get { return this.receiptEffectiveDateField; }
        set { this.receiptEffectiveDateField = value; }
    }
    
    public double FeeAmount
    {
        get { return this.feeAmountField; }
        set { this.feeAmountField = value; }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that, when I inspect the FeeAmount property in the builtObject (before adding it to the list), it shows the correct value, for example, 0. However, after adding the object to the FeeTypesList, when I inspect the FeeAmount property within the list, it shows -0. I've attached screenshots for reference:
[FeeAmount property value in the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJjCS.png)
[FeeAmount value in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jKew.png)

I've thoroughly debugged each step but couldn't find why it's showing -0 after adding to the list. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the value after the adding also in the debugger? What happens with values other than 0? For me, this looks like a problem in the code that displays the value.

Comment: The values other than 0 are showing correctly. Only in case of 0 some are added as 0 some are added as -0.

Comment: I suppose this is a rounding issue where the number is printed. Locate that part of the code and check the exact value (it might be -0.00000000001 or something)

Comment: I thought the same remove round operation but it is coming 0 only but after adding into list I am seeing -0.

Comment: Show the code that prints the number.